# Создание элементов с помощью js

Tags: javascript

Как создать элемент с помощью ``- такой строки чтобы передать переменные, 
при createElement создается просто пустой div.

Comment: А какие "переменные" вы хотите передать создаваемому элементу?

Comment: приведи пример строки

Comment: `<div class="tera${rrrrr}" rrr="${rrrrr}" id="${id}" rrt="${b}" ret="${a}">` создание таких div, чтобы динамически у них менять значения например

Comment: То-есть, вам нужно, чтоб при изменении переменных, менялось значение атрибутов?

Answer (score 2):

```
let el=document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML=content;
el.id=gggg;
//И т.д.
smthelement.appendChild(el);
```

В "такую строку ``" переменные можно вставить следующим образом:

```
let vr="no!";
//...
let str=`my str ${vr} my str`;
```

Comment: `<div class="tera${rrrrr}" rrr="${rrrrr}" id="${id}" rrt="${b}" ret="${a}">` создание таких div, чтобы динамически у них менять значения например